# SQLAlchemy events are not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I'm working with SQLAlchemy and tried to add events to my code. While everything works, the events are *not* being triggered. Here is my simplified code:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import event

alchemy_base = declarative_base()

class Person(alchemy_base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'
    name = Column(String, primary_key=True)

@event.listens_for(Person, "before_insert")
def before_insert(mapper, connection, instance):
    print("before_insert", mapper, connection, instance)

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
alchemy_base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session_maker = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = session_maker()

insert_dicts = [{'name': "ami"}, {'name': "beni"}]
engine.execute(Person.__table__.insert(), insert_dicts)
session.commit()
```

The function `before_insert` is not being called, although the values are entered into the DB.

I'm using python 2.7.10 on Mac OS, SQLAlchemy 1.0.10.

Comment: This looks right to me. Are you sure you're passing in the right values for `mapper, connection, instance` when you initially setup the event?

Comment: @Jeff-Widman: mapper, connection, instance are parameters to `before_insert`, I'm not passing them, they should have valid values when `before_insert` is called (but it does not get called). Setting up the event should be done by `@event.listens_for`.

Comment: You're right, my bad. I wonder if it has anything to do with how you're inserting? Perhaps using the `__table__.insert()` API bypasses the event system? Have you tried inserting into Person by using the official API calls for SQLAlchemy Core?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`before_insert` is an ORM event. You are using the SQLAlchemy Core instead of the ORM. This works.

```
>>> p = Person(name='Ami')
>>> session.add(p)
>>> session.commit()
2016-01-13 23:37:42,887 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
('before_insert', <Mapper at 0x1059e4dd0; Person>, <sqlalchemy.engine.base.Connection object at 0x105a2e990>, <__main__.Person object at 0x105a2e790>)
2016-01-13 23:37:42,888 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine INSERT INTO my_table (name) VALUES (?)
2016-01-13 23:37:42,888 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine ('Ami',)
2016-01-13 23:37:42,888 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
```

Comment: you are correct these listeners do not work on all levels of sqlalchemy. This not mentioned anywhere in the docs. If you post this as an answer I will accept.

Comment: how do I do this in the orm?